# Youtube Data API V3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, upload

I'm working right now on uploading youtube videos from a web client to Youtube.
I want to use Javascript to upload video and show the uploaded video before post the url uploaded to my server database.

So the first thing i did is to create an account in [Youtube console](https://console.developers.google.com). and activating Youtube Data Api and then i created an ID clients OAuth 2.0 with the type : Web application and id client has this form : 000000-x1x1x1.apps.googleusercontent.com i have also add an authorized referrer : http://127.0.0.1:3300 since i work in localhost.

So it seems that all is well configured, I've followed the official tutorial youtube gives but when i try to upload a video i had this error :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for:  is not a valid value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for:  is not a valid value"
 }
}
```

Does any one had this error?
Thanks

Comment: Any one? here is the tutorial i've followed [Youtube Tuto](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#upload_video)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out why i couldn't upload a video the tutorial Youtube gives is not complete [Youtube Javascript upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#upload_video), there is some parameters that i must send and the params i needed are title, description and finally and the most wanted privacyStatus, what i did is adding two text fields with ids #description and #title and fill those text fields with correct data And at last fill the privacyStatus with (private|public) this mean how you want your video to be uploaded.

You can update the upload js file given by Youtube like so :

```
  var metadata = {
    snippet: {
      title: $('#title').val(),
      description: $('#description').text(),
      tags: this.tags,
      categoryId: this.categoryId
    },
    status: {
      privacyStatus: "public"
    }
  };
```